# vscode configuring new shell

Tags: shell, visual-studio-code

Hi i´m trying to reconfigure the terminal of my vscode proyect to use a terminal provided by a `.bat` script that works like this:

```
shell.bat CHANGE_PATH <path where the shell open>
```

and I configure my tterminal like this

```
{
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "<path to shell.bat>",
    "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": ["CHANGE_PATH","${workspaceRoot}"]
}
```

but the ${workspaceRoot} variable did't work and the shell is opened on its default path